# E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I have checked many questions regarding this issue but none solved my case.

I run linux kali, trying to run packet tracer [image: terminal] . I have tried reinstalling packettracer but it didn't solve, I have seen many questions regarding this and tried many answers but didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which version of linux kali ? which version of packet tracer ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 I have the newest version (downloaded from the official website), patcket tracer is version 2.2